# Permissions issue with Python and ffmpeg on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, ffmpeg, anaconda

I am fairly new to Python (~4 weeks), and I have been struggling with this all day.

I am using MacOS 10.13, Python 3.7 via Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12 and Spyder 4.0.1.

Somehow (only a noob, remember) I had 2 Anaconda environments. I don't do production code, just research, so I figured I would make life simple and just use the base environment. I deleted the other environment.

I had previously got FFmpeg working and was able to do frame grabs, build mpeg animations, and convert them to gifs for blog posts and such. I had FFmpeg installed in the directories associated with the deleted environment, so it went away.

No worries, I got the git URL, used Terminal to install it in /opt/anaconda3/bin. It's all there and I can run FFmpeg from the Terminal.

My problem: When I attempt to run a module that previously worked fine, I get the following message:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg'

In my module I set the default location of FFmpeg: plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/opt/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg'

In my module I have the following lines:

```
writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=frameRate, metadata=metadata)
writer.setup(fig, "animation.mp4", 100)
```

This calls matplotlib's 'animation.py', which runs the following:

```
def setup(self, fig, outfile, dpi=None):
    '''
    Perform setup for writing the movie file.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fig : `~matplotlib.figure.Figure`
        The figure object that contains the information for frames
    outfile : str
        The filename of the resulting movie file
    dpi : int, optional
        The DPI (or resolution) for the file.  This controls the size
        in pixels of the resulting movie file. Default is fig.dpi.
    '''
    self.outfile = outfile
    self.fig = fig
    if dpi is None:
        dpi = self.fig.dpi
    self.dpi = dpi
    self._w, self._h = self._adjust_frame_size()

    # Run here so that grab_frame() can write the data to a pipe. This
    # eliminates the need for temp files.
    self._run()

def _run(self):
    # Uses subprocess to call the program for assembling frames into a
    # movie file.  *args* returns the sequence of command line arguments
    # from a few configuration options.
    command = self._args()
    _log.info('MovieWriter.run: running command: %s', command)
    PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
    self._proc = subprocess.Popen(
        command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
        creationflags=subprocess_creation_flags)
```

Everything works fine up to the last line (i.e. 'command' looks like a well-formatted FFmpeg command line, PIPE returns -1) but subprocess.Popen() bombs out with the error message above.

I have tried changing file permissions - taking a sledgehammer approach and setting everything in /opt/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg to 777, read, write, and execute. But that doesn't seem to make any difference. I really am clueless when it comes to Apple's OS, file permissions, etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: _I figured I would make life simple and just use the base environment._ This might be the problem. It’s safe to say that the majority of Conda-related issues on SO stem from using a single environment for everything, especially when it’s the base/root environment. How did you install FFmpeg? I see it’s available as [a package from conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ffmpeg), is that what you used?

Comment: @AMC thanks for replying. To install FFmpeg, I navigated to /opt/anaconda3/bin and ran "git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg". I just deleted the directory containing ffmpeg, and installed it via Anaconda Navigator (FFmpeg, ffmpeg-python, and imageio-ffmpeg). I get the same problem. Is it possible the problem is to do with creating the file "animation.mp4" rather than running FFmpeg?

Comment: I just tested opening a text file, writing to it, and closing it in the same directory I am trying to work with - worked fine. So I don't think the [problem is creating the "animation.mp4" file.

Comment: Okay. I think I figured it out. With the new installation of FFmpeg via Anaconda, I changed the path for FFmpeg to "/opt/anaconda3/bin" but it should be "/opt/anaconda/bin/ffmpeg". I bet with my original setup, where I installed from github rather than via Anaconda, my path should have been "/opt/anaconda3/ffmpeg/ffmpeg". So all is good, and I learned a bunch tracing the code through subprocess.py. So thank you to @AMC for sending me in the right direction!

Comment: _To install FFmpeg, I navigated to /opt/anaconda3/bin and ran "git clone git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg". I just deleted the directory containing ffmpeg, and installed it via Anaconda Navigator (FFmpeg, ffmpeg-python, and imageio-ffmpeg)._ Are all traces of the previous installation gone? _Okay. I think I figured it out. With the new installation of FFmpeg via Anaconda, I changed the path for FFmpeg to "/opt/anaconda3/bin" but it should be "/opt/anaconda/bin/ffmpeg"._ Is messing with paths even necessary here?

Comment: @AMC thanks again. I don't know if all traces are gone! I tried removing the path statement (plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/opt/anaconda3/bin/ffmpeg') and the module still works. So I guess having installed it correctly via Anaconda Navigator I don't need to explicitly set the path. I also managed to clean up two other installations of Python 3.7 and 3.8 from user/library/python from back in Feb when I first started learning Python. I feel like I have a clean install now, which helps with trouble-shooting.

Comment: _I feel like I have a clean install now_ As clean as it can get while also using the base environment, I guess. You should really fix that! _So I guess having installed it correctly via Anaconda Navigator I don't need to explicitly set the path._ That Conda magic ;) _I also managed to clean up two other installations of Python 3.7 and 3.8 from user/library/python from back in Feb when I first started learning Python._ You installed those yourself though, right, they're not the system versions?

Comment: Yes, I installed those myself before I discovered Anaconda! I have left the version 2.7 that comes with macOS. You seem quite keen that I should use environments, is there a good article I could study that explains the pros and cons of environments vs using base only?

Comment: _Is there a good article I could study that explains the pros and cons of environments vs using base only?_ I don't know of any decent articles on the subject, it's mostly based on my experiences right here on SO. Separating and isolating projects is a good idea in general, regardless of whether you're using Python. That's the whole point of using virtual environments, right?

Comment: Well, I don't know. The closest I ever got to using virtual environments is storing my research projects in their own directories! I guess I shall just keep reading about the topic until I find something that works for my needs. Thanks again for your guidance! Ian.